# How do i get the current period or most recent anniversary (month or year) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I have two tables (although they could be merged into one): one that has a period indicator (0 = year, 1 = month) and one that contains the start date. A period can be either a month or a year and I need to find out when the current period is.

table A:

```
id  type
7       1 
269     1
270     1
271     0
```

table B:

```
id  start   end
7   24-11-2013  31-12-2099
9   24-11-2013  31-12-2099
10  28-11-2013  28-11-2014
271 20-12-2013  31-12-2099
```

Now I need to find the date that current period started for each id in table B. So for example:

1. id 7 has start '24-11-2013', type = 1 (monthly), today is '07-05-2015' -> current start is '24-04-2015'
2. id 271 has start '20-12-2013', type = 0 (yearly), today is '07-05-2015' -> current start is '20-12-2014'

Can I achieve this is pure MySQL only?

EDIT: please note that I used DD-MM-YYYY notation for the dates. I apologize if this is/was confusing

Comment: what should it do if type=1 or 0?

Comment: if type = 1 then I want the date that the last active month started based on the current date & start date, if type = 0 I want the date that the last active YEAR started based on the current date & start date. Please refer to the example on the bottom.

Comment: your question is unclear,from where did 20-12-2014 come from?

Comment: @SpringLearner That's one year more than '20-12-2013' and is the current active year based on the fact that id 271 has a start date of '20-12-2013'. I'll edit the post to make clear that dates are DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: so basically you want is if its yearly then db value +1 year and its monthly then db value -1 month

Comment: @SpringLearner I don't completely understand what you mean. I don't want the current date - 1 month/year if that's what you mean.

Comment: what is your exact requirement

Comment: the exact requirement is already in the question. @user1914292 for the love of god please convert the dates to a date field, rather than that format - it would make life easier

Comment: @pala_ agreed with the date format - please feel free to use that, I can get that fixed in the database

Comment: What data type do you use to store your dates as? (i.e. is are you just formatting them here as dd-MM-yyyy format, or are they actually stored as strings?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting case.  We can do it with a conditional statement that takes a different action depending on the relationship between the current date, and the start date.

```
set @when = "2015-03-01";

select b.start, 
       b.end, 
       case when type = 1 then
         case 
           when day(@when) < day(b.start) then
             b.start + interval abs(
               period_diff(
                 concat(
                   year(b.start), 
                   lpad(month(b.start), 2, "0")
                  ), 
                  concat(
                    year(@when), 
                    lpad(month(@when), 2, "0")
                  )
               )) -1 month 
           when day(@when) >= day(b.start) then
             b.start + interval abs(
               period_diff(
                 concat(
                   year(b.start), 
                   lpad(month(b.start), 2, "0")
                  ), 
                  concat(
                    year(@when), 
                    lpad(month(@when), 2, "0")
                  )
               )) month          
         end 
         when type = 0 then
           b.start + interval (year(@when) - YEAR(b.start) - (date_format(@when, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(b.start, '%m%d'))) year          
         end current_period_start
  from tableb b
    inner join tablea a
      on b.id = a.id;
```

It should correctly handle things like leap years, february having fewer days than other months etc.  In this case, i've used a variable to hold the current date, simply to aid in testing those various scenarios. You can simply replace `@when` with `now()` everywhere in the query to compare against the current date.

`period_diff` is a function that calculates the difference in months between two dates, but it's moronic in that it doesn't take an actual date argument, but rather a string in the form of 'yyyymm'.

Anyway, as far as the query goes, if `type = 1`, it finds the difference in months between the two dates, and adds it to the start date to get the most recent monthly anniversary. It also checks the day of the month to see if the anniversary fell in the current month, or the previous, and if the previous, subtracts 1 from the calculated difference, because again, `period_diff` is moronic and doesn't take into account the days.

The year calculation is simpler, simply returns the difference in years, and then subtracts either 1 or 0, depending on if our month and day is less than the starting month and day.

There's a demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/683c19/3)

Comment: Thanks, I don't really grab it yet, but the fiddle only shows one result correctly. The second one (even if I fix the schema) shows null...

Comment: @user1914292 sorry about that, i forgot to execute the updated query (i was testing in local because sqlfiddle is slow as molasses for me right now). If you'd pasted the above query in, it would have worked. Anyway, the fiddle link is updated